# Copy image in to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I had an image in my project which I removed (remove references) due to not needing it.

It transpires that I actually do need it, however now when I try to copy it back I get the following error - even though the image is not in my images folder any more - how is this fixed?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the folder (in Finder) that your app is contained in. A shortcut is to right click on an object and choose "Show in finder". Once you're in the folder, hunt around for an image named "962-puzzle-piece@2x.png". When you find it, delete it (drag it to the trash).

When you 'remove references', Xcode leaves the image in the project folder, and simply doesn't show it to you. Then when you try to add an image of the same name, it fails because there's already an image by that name in the folder Xcode tries to add it to.

You can avoid this entirely by selecting "Move to Trash" in this dialog when you delete things:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder -> Show in finder.
Then drag the real file to the trash.